# Change color of tab characters in Sublime Text 3 theme

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme, sublime-text-plugin

I am using the [Fortran](https://github.com/315234/SublimeFortran) text highlighting package for ST3, and I am making a theme using [this fantastic homepage](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai).

But see the image below. Where there are `tab characters` **within** the code (not indentation), those are colored in pink. How can I change that color, or remove it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure it helps but I noticed that when transforming indentation from tab to space the invalid pink highlights go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some trial and error I found that the property is indeed a variable on [this page](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai) and it's called `Invalid`. That is also the name in the `.tmTheme` file. But on the site there are no such characters in the sample code (that I saw) and the name isn't obviously related to the tab characters in my code.

The pink was in fact the default `Invalid` color on the theme editor site.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences, default file settings you get this instruction for changing the width and color of indent guides.

```
// Set to false to turn off the indentation guides.
// The color and width of the indent guides may be customized by editing
// the corresponding .tmTheme file, and specifying the colors "guide",
// "activeGuide" and "stackGuide"
"draw_indent_guides": true,
```

Comment: That seem to be reffering to something else: marking blank characters with dots and lines. But after adding `"draw_indent_guides": true` to my user settings, AND removing it again, I am stuck with tab characters being converted to spaces. Despite not changing the setting for that.

Comment: you may try to `"draw_indent_guides": false,` to solve that and to change the color on tmTheme file change like it `<key>guide</key>
<string>#073642</string>`

Comment: In fact, i meant to write `"draw_indent_guides": false` screwd it up. But Ill try the putting in and removing the "true" version. Anyway, I found the solution to my problem, and it was mostly my own fault, and not related to guides, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to remove those, since they are not supposed to be there. They are referenced as `Invalid` token which can show signs for deprecation, unreadable code etc. It is supposed to look like:

```
diff = first - second
```

and not

```
diff      = first    -  second
```

If you really want to overwrite that, you can edit the syntax definition file or overwrite it in your `User` folder.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Preferences -> Browse Packages -> Fortran -> grammars
- Open `FortranModern.sublime-syntax` or `FortranFixedForm.sublime-syntax`
- Remove the following lines

`# tabs are illegal
    - match: \t
      scope: invalid.illegal.tab.fortran`

- Done?

PS: A [pull request](https://github.com/315234/SublimeFortran/pull/32) to fix this has already been merged so next builds should be fine